# sequelize.query method formats dates differently after 1.7.0-rc1 upgrade

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

We just updated to sequelize version 1.7.0-rc1.  All of a sudden the following sequelize code stopped working:

```
exports.invalidate = function (partnerId, importStartTime, fn) {
  console.log('\r\n Import start time:  ' + JSON.stringify(importStartTime));

  var sql = '';
  sql += 'UPDATE "Product" p SET "status" = 0 FROM "Brand" b WHERE b."id" = p."BrandId" AND b."PartnerId" = ' + partnerId + ' AND p."status" <> 0 AND \
            p."validatedAt" < \'' + importStartTime + '\'; ';

  sql += 'UPDATE "Variant" v SET "status" = 0 FROM "Product" p INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE \
            p."id" = v."ProductId" AND b."PartnerId" = ' + partnerId + ' AND v."status" <> 0 AND v."validatedAt" < \'' + importStartTime + '\'; ';

  sql += 'UPDATE "ProductCategory" pc SET "status" = 0 FROM "Product" p INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE \
            p."id" = pc."ProductId" AND b."PartnerId" = ' + partnerId + ' AND pc."status" <> 0 AND pc."validatedAt" < \'' + importStartTime + '\'; ';

  sql += 'UPDATE "VariantImg" vi SET "status" = 0 FROM "Variant" v INNER JOIN "Product" p ON p."id" = v."ProductId" INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE \
            v."id" = vi."VariantId" AND b."PartnerId" = ' + partnerId + ' AND vi."status" <> 0 AND vi."validatedAt" < \'' + importStartTime + '\'; ';

  console.log('\r\n ' + sql);
  sequelize.query(sql).success(function () {
    console.log('\r\n Invalidation completed :)');

    fn(null);
  }).error(function (err) {
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n Invalidation failed :(');
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n Sequelize failed to set status to 0 for items that have been invalidated :(');
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n err:  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    fn(err);
  });
}
```

We are using PostgreSql v9.3 for our datastore and it appears that the Update (sql) is not being executed.  If I execute the same sql directly in PostgreSql, everything works as expected.  The funny thing is, if I enable sequelize logging, I can see the Update statments being logged.

**Update: 1/23/2014**

I decided to move the Update SQL to a PosgreSql function.  Strangely, the result is the same .  If I call the function within PosgreSql, everything works.  If I call the function from Sequelize, via the sequelize.query method, the same problem occurs.

Here is the code for the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invalidate(partnerId INTEGER, importStartTime TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS TABLE (
  validatedAt TIMESTAMP,
  importStartTime2 TIMESTAMP
)
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE "Product" p SET "status" = 0 FROM "Brand" b WHERE b."id" = p."BrandId" AND b."PartnerId" = $1 AND p."status" <> 0 AND             
    p."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE < $2; 

    UPDATE "Variant" v SET "status" = 0 FROM "Product" p INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE             
    p."id" = v."ProductId" AND b."PartnerId" = $1 AND v."status" <> 0 AND 
    v."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE < $2; 

    UPDATE "ProductCategory" pc SET "status" = 0 FROM "Product" p INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE             
    p."id" = pc."ProductId" AND b."PartnerId" = $1 AND pc."status" <> 0 AND 
    pc."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE < $2; 

    UPDATE "VariantImg" vi SET "status" = 0 FROM "Variant" v INNER JOIN "Product" p ON p."id" = v."ProductId" INNER JOIN "Brand" b ON b."id" = p."BrandId" WHERE             
    v."id" = vi."VariantId" AND b."PartnerId" = $1 AND vi."status" <> 0 AND 
    vi."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE < $2;

    RETURN QUERY select pc."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE as "validatedAt", $2 as "importStartTime"
          from "ProductCategory" pc
          inner join "Product" p on pc."ProductId" = p."id"
          inner join "Brand" b on b."id" = p."BrandId"
          where pc."id" = 34;


END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I call the function like so within PosgreSql, all is fine:

```
SELECT invalidate(31, '2014-01-22 22:27:53');
```

If I call the function like so from node.js using Sequelize, it doesn't work:

```
var sql = 'SELECT invalidate(' + partnerId + ', \'' + importStartTime + '\');';
  console.log('\r\n ' + sql);

  sequelize.query(sql).success(function (data) {
    //console.log('\r\n Invalidation completed :)');
    console.log('\r\n data:  ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    fn(null);
  }).error(function (err) {
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n Invalidation failed :(');
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n Sequelize failed to set status to 0 for items that have been invalidated :(');
    logExceptOnTest('\r\n err:  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    fn(err);
  });
```

I have narrowed down the problem to this part of the sql:

```
p."validatedAt"::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE < $2
```

I believe the problem is with how dates are stored and passed by both PostgreSql and Sequelize.  Somthing changed with Sequelize 1.7.0-rc1, that is converting the date to a format that doesn't match what PosgreSql is reading from the validatedAt timestamp column.
I played around for a while, by attempting to message the dates into the right UTC format.  I tried both with and without time zone, without any success.  I even added a select at the end of the function to return me the date which is stored in the validatedAt column and the date I pass into the function (importStartTime).  Both dates are clearly the same when looking at them visually in the code (via console.log) and in the table (when selected directly in PostgreSql), but when the function call returns the results of it's select statement, the dates are not in the same format.  So, I believe the Update statment's date comparison part is also seeing the dates in different format and thus making it appear that the query is not working, even though it actually is.

I updated the title of this post to reflect the new findings.

Comment: "stopped working", "it appears", ... ? If you look at the PostgreSQL server logs, do you see the `UPDATE`s there? (You might need to set `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf`. Are there any subsequent errors or `ROLLBACK`s that would undo the changes?

Comment: So, I checked the PostgreSQL server logs and I don't see the Update statements being logged.  It looks like Sequelize logs the Update statements but they are still not being executed by PostgreSql.  Note, we were using the same version of PosgreSql before and after the Sequelize upgrade.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some framework debugging ahead of you! Yay! Do make sure that other `UPDATE`s get logged, i.e. the Pg logs are actually recording update statements at all and it's really Sequelize not sending them, though. My first guess would be that Sequelize doesn't like the multi-statement string. BTW, is there any chance you can use parameterized statements rather than sending a block of string-concatenated SQL like that? it's kinda ugly, and if you ever have improperly sanitized input you're up for an SQL injection hole.

Comment: Craig, I had some new findings which narrow down the problem to a date format issue.  I updated my main post above.  Yes, I will eventually modify the code to use parameterized statements (thanks for the suggestion).  However, I am not worried about sql injection since both concatenated values are generated within the code itself and are never passed in from an outside source.